# Are there any frameworks for doing realtime models in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I know of https://github.com/andyet/Capsule
and https://github.com/codeparty/racer

Are there any more??

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind

this connects backbone models to a node server using socket.io